# How to override Session by using a module?

Tags: overrides

I'm using magento 1.4.1.1. I'm looking for a way to make a new module override "/var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php".
I know how overriding controllers, but models. My files are as follows, most of them might be wrong... My new module is called "ModulePendingApproval".
Please don't hesitate do provide code snippets as I'm new in magento.

/var/www/app/code/local/Lpf/ModulePendingApproval/Model/Session.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Customer
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Customer session model
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Customer
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Customer_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Customer object
     *
     * @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    protected $_customer;

    /**
     * Flag with customer id validations result
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isCustomerIdChecked = null;

    /**
     * Retrieve customer sharing configuration model
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Config_Share
     */
    public function getCustomerConfigShare()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/config_share');
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $namespace = 'customer';
        if ($this->getCustomerConfigShare()->isWebsiteScope()) {
            $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
        }

        $this->init($namespace);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
    }

    /**
     * Set customer object and setting customer id in session
     *
     * @param   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
     * @return  Mage_Customer_Model_Session
     */
    public function setCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        // check if customer is not confirmed
        if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
                throw new Exception('This customer is not confirmed and cannot log in.',
                    Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
                );
            }
        }
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->setId($customer->getId());
        // save customer as confirmed, if it is not
        if ((!$customer->isConfirmationRequired()) && $customer->getConfirmation()) {
            $customer->setConfirmation(null)->save();
            $customer->setIsJustConfirmed(true);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve costomer model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if ($this->_customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
            return $this->_customer;
        }

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        if ($this->getId()) {
            $customer->load($this->getId());
        }

        $this->setCustomer($customer);
        return $this->_customer;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer id from current session
     *
     * @return int || null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->getId();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer group id
     * If customer is not logged in system not logged in group id will be returned
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCustomerGroupId()
    {
        if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        } else {
            return Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking custommer loggin status
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->getId() && (bool)$this->checkCustomerId($this->getId());
    }

    /**
     * Check exists customer (light check)
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkCustomerId($customerId)
    {
        if ($this->_isCustomerIdChecked === null) {
            $this->_isCustomerIdChecked = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->checkCustomerId($customerId);
        }
        return $this->_isCustomerIdChecked;
    }

    /**
     * Customer authorization
     *
     * @param   string $username
     * @param   string $password
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        if ($customer->authenticate($username, $password)) {
            Mage::log(__METHOD__ . ' access granted !!');
            $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
    {
        $this->setCustomer($customer);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Authorization customer by identifier
     *
     * @param   int $customerId
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function loginById($customerId)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Logout customer
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
            $this->setId(null);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate controller action by login customer
     *
     * @param   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $action
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function authenticate(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $action, $loginUrl = null)
    {
        if (!$this->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true)));
            if (is_null($loginUrl)) {
                $loginUrl = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();
            }
            $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($loginUrl);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

/var/www/app/code/local/Lpf/ModulePendingApproval/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
    </modules>

</config>
```

/var/www/app/etc/modules/Lpf_ModulePendingApproval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To overwrite a model class your `config.xml` would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
    </modules>
   <global>
      <models>
         <customer>
            <rewrite>
               <session>Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Session<session>
            </rewrite>
         </customer>
      </models>
   </global>
</config>
```

And the new `Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Session` class that overwrites something like this

```
class Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Session extends Mage_Customer_Model_Session
{
   // your custom code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The class name from the file `Lpf/ModulePendingApproval/Model/Session.php` should be

`Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Session` and it should extend `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`.

You should also add this inside the `config.xml` file of your module inside the `config` tag

```
<global>
    <models>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <session>Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Session</session>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </models>
</global>
```

clear the cache and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some help on how to rewrite a model [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

But obviously you also need some tips on how to build a module, so you can read [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/) too (especially the chapter *"Configuring Our Model’s Directory"*).

Comment: Please add relevant code snippets from the links you provide. Links might die making the answer less relevant :)

Comment: You're right. But your answer make it clear so i don't have anymore. :D

Comment: But I'll do it on my next posts/answers